# Sum of alternating 2 elements

Tags: sum

I have an array like this
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

if I want to execute the sum of each alternating two elements, like 1+2, then 5+6, then 9+10, how the code should be written? I can do the sum of each 2 elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular, How do I ask a good question? and What topics can I ask about here?. From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a for loop do so.

```js
var c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var sum = [];

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i += 2)
  sum.push(c[i] + c[i+1])

for (var j = 0; j < sum.length; j++)
  console.log(sum[j]);
```